# A way to setup breakpoints in Immunity Debugger using commands?

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, malware

I am looking to set up breakpoints before I start debugging in Immunity, like I do with x32/64dbg. `bp VirtualAlloc / bp WriteProcessMemory` and the like. Is there a way I can do this without having to search through the code for these commands?

Comment: You can use the Immunity Debugger's built-in python API. Something like this should do the trick:

    `imm.setBreakpoint(imm.getAddress("ws2_32.VirtualAlloc"))`


 Some more details here: https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/analysis-of-malware-samples/#gref

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the feedback